# Pandas rename inflates HDF file size

Tags: pandas, hdf5, pytables

I have fairly perplexing problem with the df.rename() method and renaming in general.  No matter how I attempt to rename a column in an existing dataframe, the resulting HDF output is doubled in size.  Unlike most numerical only frames, my frames do include many unicode columns that are treated as objects.

I've tried the following cases but all seem to significantly inflate the resulting HDF file generated using df.to_hdf('some_file.h5', 'table').

Assuming I have a renaming dictionary called rename_dict that looks like:

```
rename_dict = {'old_column': 'new_column'}
```

**Case A** (Using inplace):

```
df.rename(columns=rename_dict, inplace=True)
```

**Case B** (Not using inplace):

```
df_renamed = df.rename(columns=rename_dict)
```

**Case C** (Manual remap and remove):

```
df['new_name'] = df['old_name]
del df['old_name']
```

I feel like I must be missing some crucial understanding of how this renaming action is occurring and thus creating extra data in the HDF file.

I'm not sure if it is relevant to this problem but I do receive performance warnings about objects not mapping to c-types.  Although, while this is bad, without applying any sort of renaming operation, the file size is "correct" so I have discounted that as a root cause.

Any insight (or solution) would be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C, see [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#compression)

In a nutshell, for performance reasons, deletions don't actually delete data. A rename is simply a delete followed by an append. You can simply `ptrepack` your file to reclaim the space (or create a new one). HDF5 is NOT a regular database. It is performant for certain types of operations, namely appending, and querying.

You ought to try using the `table` format to eliminate those warnings. In general you are probably trying to store non-natives types, which get *pickled*, see [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#performance)

A and B are in-memory operations, having nothing to do with an HDF5 file.

Comment: Agree that A and B are all in memory.  I am reading a file (.csv) into memory performing the rename and only then saving it to HDF5.  As soon as I apply the rename method to the frame, it doubles the output size.  If I omit the rename method the file size is half.  Since all operations are performed in memory with the writing to HDF only happening at the end, I can't seem to understand why the rename method would seem to cause the frame to double in size and thus create a double-sized HDF file.

Comment: are you starting with an empty file? (e.g. ``mode='w'``), each time?, tables by definition append. So if you run your script twice it will append twice.

Comment: You should update your cases to reflect what's going on. Are you doing `df = pd.read_csv(); df.to_hdf()` and getting a file with `x` bytes. Compared to `df = pd.read_csv(); `df = df.rename(columns=rename_dict); df.to_hdf()` and getting a file with `2x` bytes?

Comment: Write the second one to a different file from the first to make sure it isn't appending.

Comment: the ptrepack post HDF write was the trick to this.  I still am unsure why in-memory pandas operations manifest themselves in the HDF whether I use pd.to_hdf or the HDFStore directly but this solves my problem for now.  Many thanks...